# How to count a number from different table when there's no common field?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

There are a user table and a user_follow table that describes which `user.id` is following/followed. I'd like to count the occurrences of that user is following and being followed.

The problem is that user_follow table doesn't have user_id as a `foreign key`, so I'm not able to join [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej9l4.png) the two tables by a common field. I've tried to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on `user.id=user_follow.following_user_id and GROUP BY user.id`, but it only counts the times of following(followed times is exactly the same as the following, which is not right).

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this is to join on USER_FOLLOW twice, once for Followed By and once for Following.

You haven't posted the structure of USER_FOLLOW, so this is a guess and you'll need to correct it to fit your schema.

```
select u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name
       , count(f.following_user_id) as following_count
       , count(fb.user_id) as followed_by_count
from user u
     left_outer join user_follow f on where f.user_id = u.id
     left_outer join user_follow fb on where fb.following_user_id = u.id
group by u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name
```